# Viewing an inline HTML text using QWebView()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwebview

I'm creating an application using PyQt4 to be able to view an inline text HTML mark-up without loading a local HTML file from the system. 
But, i got some problem with the string format of the HTML.This code is showing only the Window not the HTML text. Please help.

```
# imported all the modules

class HtmlView(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        .................
        # i've skipped the layout definition here
        ................

        # an inline text with html mark-up

        text = "<p>This is  a paragraph</p><div>This is inside div   element</div>" 

        self.html = QtWebKit.QWebView()

        # setting layout
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.html)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.web_page = text
        url = self.web_page
        self.html.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.html.show()

# executing using if __name__ == "main": skipped this part
```

And please tell me how to change the style of elements <p> and <div> inside the QWebView().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [setHtml](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#setHtml) to load markup in the webview:

```
    self.html = QtWebKit.QWebView()
    # self.web_page = text
    # url = self.web_page
    self.html.setHtml(text)
    # self.html.show()
```

(The commented lines aren't needed).

To style the elements, add a stylesheet to your markup:

```
    text = """
        <html>
        <style type="text/css">
            p {color: red}
            div {color: blue}
        </style>
        <body>   
        <p>This is  a paragraph</p>
        <div>This is inside div element</div>
        </body>   
        </html>
    """
```

PS: using a QWebView for displaying markup is a very heavy-weight solution - it might be better to use [QTextBrowser](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextbrowser.html) instead (which is much easier to use). This only has support for a [limited subset of HTML](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html), but it is usually good enough:

```
    self.html = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self)
    self.html.setHtml(text)
```

Comment: thanks once again @ekhumoro.. I'm new in Gui programming and PyQt4..so dont mind if my questions are stupid... your solutions works well..thanks :)